# After upgrading to flutter 3.3.0 I got these errors

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, flutter-3.0, flatbutton

Currently, I am having this error:

```
 Warning: Mapping new ns http://schemas.android.com/repository/android/common/02 to old ns http://schemas.android.com/repository/android/common/01
    Warning: Mapping new ns http://schemas.android.com/repository/android/generic/02 to old ns http://schemas.android.com/repository/android/generic/01
    Warning: Mapping new ns http://schemas.android.com/sdk/android/repo/addon2/02 to old ns http://schemas.android.com/sdk/android/repo/addon2/01
    Warning: Mapping new ns http://schemas.android.com/sdk/android/repo/repository2/02 to old ns http://schemas.android.com/sdk/android/repo/repository2/01
    Warning: Mapping new ns http://schemas.android.com/sdk/android/repo/sys-img2/02 to old ns http://schemas.android.com/sdk/android/repo/sys-img2/01
    ../../../DEV/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/flutter_xlider-3.4.0/lib/flutter_xlider.dart:322:19: Error: No named parameter with the name 'overflow'.
                      overflow: Overflow.visible,
                      ^^^^^^^^
    ../../../DEV/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/widgets/basic.dart:3787:3: Context: Found this candidate, but the arguments don't match.
      Stack({
      ^^^^^
    ../../../DEV/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/flutter_rounded_date_picker-3.0.1/lib/src/flutter_rounded_button_action.dart:36:35: Error: The method 'FlatButton' isn't defined for the class 'FlutterRoundedButtonAction'.
     - 'FlutterRoundedButtonAction' is from 'package:flutter_rounded_date_picker/src/flutter_rounded_button_action.dart' ('../../../DEV/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/flutter_rounded_date_picker-3.0.1/lib/src/flutter_rounded_button_action.dart').
```

I got these errors after upgrading flutter SDK from 2.2.3 to 3.3.0.

Comment: https://docs.flutter.dev/release/breaking-changes/clip-behavior

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As pskink commented,

> For the Stack widget specifically, if you previously used `overflow: Overflow.visible`, replace it with `clipBehavior: Clip.none`.

Find more about [clip-behavior#migration-guide](https://docs.flutter.dev/release/breaking-changes/clip-behavior#migration-guide)